# Javascript - Equel height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
equalheight = function(container){

    var currentTallest = 0,
         currentRowStart = 0,
         rowDivs = new Array(),
         jQueryel,
         topPosition = 0;
     jQuery(container).each(function() {

       jQueryel = jQuery(this);
       jQuery(jQueryel).height('auto')
       topPostion = jQueryel.position().top;

       if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
         for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
           rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
         }
         rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
         currentRowStart = topPostion;
         currentTallest = jQueryel.height();
         rowDivs.push(jQueryel);
       } else {
         rowDivs.push(jQueryel);
         currentTallest = (currentTallest < jQueryel.height()) ? (jQueryel.height()) : (currentTallest);
      }
       for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
         rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
       }
     });
    }

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
     equalheight('.test-class');
    });


    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        equalheight('.test-class');
    });
```

hey guys I'm using this to make all divs in equal height. Its not working properly. But when we open the inspect element its working. Can guys know about that?

Comment: What's "not working properly"? Can you be a bit more specific about what happens?

Comment: Suppose we are repeating ".test-class" and if those divs should have equal height generating automatically. For that we can use this script.

Comment: This script is working like which div has more content that height will share to other divs detecting automatically.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css flex to make them equal height. You are ending up writing more code by doing it via javascript. This is simplest solution, and you can also add margin padding and whatever you want to the divs.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #343434;
}
.col {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.s6 { background-color: #7dc242; }
.s7 { background-color: #ed1c24; }
.s8 { background-color: #EEEEEE; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
        <div class="panel">
            content1
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            content2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s7">
         <div class="panel">
            content3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s8">
         <div class="panel">
            content4
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            content5
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            content6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```